# Cannot find a version of 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-debug

[image: thats the error]

> Cannot find a version of 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' that
>   satisfies the version constraints

```
   Dependency path 'Kmrider5:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
   Constraint path 'Kmrider5:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' strictly '1.3.9' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Dependency path 'Kmrider5:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
   Constraint path 'Kmrider5:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' strictly '1.3.9' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Dependency path 'Kmrider5:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
   Constraint path 'Kmrider5:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' strictly '1.3.9' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Dependency path 'Kmrider5:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
   Constraint path 'Kmrider5:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' strictly '1.3.9' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Dependency path 'Kmrider5:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
   Constraint path 'Kmrider5:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' strictly '1.3.9' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Dependency path 'Kmrider5:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
   Constraint path 'Kmrider5:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' strictly '1.3.9' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
   Dependency path 'Kmrider5:app:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
   Dependency path 'Kmrider5:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0' --> 'com.google.guava:guava:23.5-android' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
```

Answer (score 2):

That means you are importing some gradle libraries depending on 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' but different versions.
You should evaluate whether to update libraries versions or exclude the implicit import of the findbugs library from some of them.

I got this error when I added Espresso to an already-created project and solved by excluding findbugs from the Espresso's libraries imports.

**A solution**

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305'
}
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because it was moved. Here is a link explaining.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/findbugs/